# Manipulating QAndroidJniObject array

Tags: java, c++, arrays, qt

When I return a string from java method in MyActivity, I can print it with

```
QAndroidJniObject asdf = QtAndroid::androidActivity().callObjectMethod("getPath", "(I)Ljava/lang/String;", 10)

qInfo() << asdf.toString();
```

But What if I want to return an array? How to manipulate it with C++ and how to print it out?

```
public class MyActivity extends QtActivity
{

    private String [] imagePaths = new String[100];

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       //some code
    }

    public String [] getPath (int index) {

        /*some code*/
        return imagePaths;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your task better to use

```
jobjectArray asdf = QtAndroid::androidActivity()
        .callMethod<jobjectArray>("getPath", "(I)Ljava/lang/String;", 10);
```

Instead

```
QAndroidJniObject asdf = QtAndroid::androidActivity()
        .callObjectMethod("getPath", "(I)Ljava/lang/String;", 10)
```